# Common tool to run softwares in cross platform operating systems?

Tags: windows, linux, macos, software-rec

#### Scenario and example

In Windows the software usually comes with the extension `.exe`, we used to run `.exe` files in Linux operating systems using some third party tool like *wine*, likewise there may be a separate tool for running Windows files on Mac operatingsystem.

#### What I need

Is it there any **global tool** which can be used at any platform for the following:

1. To run `.exe` files on Linux & Mac?
2. To run Mac OS X software packages on Windows & Linux?
3. To run Mac, Linux software packages on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

There is no monolithic single tool that provides everything needed to run any native OSX, Linux or Windows app unaltered on *all* of those operating systems.

---

[WINE](http://www.winehq.org/) runs many Windows apps on Linux and OS X.

You can run Linux apps in a Linux VM on Windows. See VMWare, VirtualBox, etc See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_platform_virtual_machines

Using [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) "You must rebuild your application from source if you want it to run on Windows."

---

An alternative approach to this problem is the bytecode approach used by Java and (to a lesser extent) by .Net. However this doesn't help with existing native apps.

Comment: sir but wine can't run on mac

Comment: @Nikitha: "Run Windows applications on Linux, BSD, Solaris and Mac OS X."  is the strapline at Wine's website.

Comment: but how can i inverse it,for e.g using linux,mac,solaris applications on windows

Comment: redgrittybrick  sir,then my condition 2 doesnt satisfy

Comment: @Nikitha: You are right, I'll update answer.

Comment: The simple answer is no; like the first line in the answer. Each platform needs the source to be compiled for its own architecture and framework. The difficult answer is Yes. Compile it yourself in the environment you want (if source is available) people have been doing that for donkeys years.

Comment: @ppumkin i agree but i asked this question for changing the usual nature ,maybe we have to wait for such an kind of tool

Comment: I doubt it! Because then you will want to run JavaSDK in your cars ECU and possibly .NET4.5 on your toaster to send you a tweet when the toast is ready too. Peoples efforts to do what you want boil down to emulation like Wine and all that jazz. Each OS can do anything another can - the tools just have different names.